# WiX - Renaming files/folders in next versions of setup

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action

We have a product that we install using WiX, and we have done some re-branding, and I would like to change some things in installation paths and file names.

So, when I make a new version of our installation, the folder with old name remains in Start menu, for example. Also, if I rename a file, the old versions are not deleted, either.

I would like to know what would be the best way of installing files with new names over previous versions of installation.

Comment: I believe the CopyFile element will do what you want. http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd%5Cwix%5Ccopyfile.html

Comment: @PeterRitchie The files will sometimes have to be installed, I don't know if that's the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're doing a major upgrade with a [late scheduling of RemoveExistingProducts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Sequence_Restrictions). When you do that, you have to strictly follow the component rules. My [blog post on upgrades](http://www.joyofsetup.com/2008/12/30/paying-for-upgrades/) covers ways of avoiding that, such as by using an early scheduling of RemoveExistingProducts.

Comment: Yeah, I guess the default setting is late scheduling of RemoveExistingProducts. However, I seem to have made another mistake along the way by setting generated GUID on Start menu component. I noticed it "broke" and my uninstalls haven't been removing files in Start menu folder at all. It seems to me like I can't fix it without a version between that will resolve all the current issues and have roughly the same configuration as current installation. Can you confirm that is the only way to go? (excluding some solution that uses custom actions to try forcing removal of files)

Comment: Hard to say without knowing exactly what's going on but in general, if you've already released a "broken" installer, you'll have to fix its problems first. You can avoid component GUID problems in general by using Guid="*" to have WiX generate a GUID based on the target path.

Comment: I think I realized that too late, but I get it now. I guess I will have to go for the custom action to do it. I think I could try and remove other folder when installing newer version, but not quite sure how it will work with per-user installation.